# How to save powershell command as variable?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get this command

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -like "*$fileGuid*") } | Select-Object Name,Directory`

and store it in a variable that can be called later like this

$test = `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -like "*$fileGuid*") } | Select-Object Name,Directory`

and then be able to call that variable like this

```
$test[0].Name or $test[0].Directory
```

is this possible ?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question already: `$var = ...` is how you capture a command's output in a variable.

Comment: What problem are you solving?

Comment: it doesnt capture the output of that command tho?

Comment: i want to store the output of the above mentioned commands and then be able to call the commands in the above mentioned way

Comment: If it doesn't capture anything, the implication is that _your command produces no output_. Verify by running it without the assignment.

Comment: i have run it without with the assignment it produces output it just doesnt output anything when i go echo $test

Comment: i have tested this, i wouldnt post this before testing in the shell

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: On a side not: assigning to a variable captures only _success stream_ output, not other kinds of output (by default).

Comment: how much more code do you need? There is no more code relevant to this situation,

Comment: what does that mean ?

Comment: Are you looking to capture the _result_ of the command, or are you trying to cause the retrieval of the variable to _execute_ the command, and produce results fresh?

Comment: i want to capture the result, but i also want to be able to call individual properties such as directory and name in the above mentioned post.

Comment: if it is not possible i will have to try another method if it is possible and someone knows how to make it work i would greatly appreciate it .

Comment: What you've posted doesn't explain your symptom - and that's precisely the problem: if the code looks correct but mysteriously only doesn't work for _you_, how do you expect others to help? The _verifiable_ aspect of an MCVE is crucial.

Comment: look at the answer below

Comment: Look at my comment to the answer below: The use of `(...)` is superfluous and doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the result of the command, enclose the entire command in parentheses `(` and `)` before assigning to the variable, i.e.,

```
$test = (Get-ChildItem ...)
```

This will cause `$test` to be an array of whatever object your command returns, and you can then refer to the various properties and methods as `$test[n].property`, e.g., `$test[1].Name`.

Comment: While this works, it doesn't explain the OP's symptom (and we don't have enough information to explain them at this point). There is no need for parentheses, and the parentheses themselves do not ensure that the output is an _array_ (which is usually not necessary) - for that, you'd have to use `@(...)`.

Comment: i dont understand what you want? There is two variables in my command the filepath and file guid that are static coded. therefore the command works. you can try it yourself with your own variables and it will return a file location in your directory.

Comment: Actually, I think it may be version-dependent with the PowerShell version. When I tried it here on a PS2 system, `$test = Get-ChildItem` only caused `$test` to contain the string `Get-ChildItem`, but could be executed with `&$test`. However, with PS5, `$test` was in fact assigned the output of `Get-ChildItem`, and could then be referenced as querent desired.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I just tried on PSv2 system, and it seems to work just like in PSv5.1 - no `(...)` necessary, and an unquoted alphanumeric token is interpreted as a _command_. If you run `$v = Get-Date; $v` in PSv2 on your machine, do you really not get the current date as the output?

Comment: That is exactly what happens here. I also won't rule out that there's some sort of weird Group Policy issue going on here; we've successfully done stuff with Group Policy that even Microsoft didn't believe was possible...

Comment: So what do you get when you run my command? Are you running it in the console? And what is the type of the value created?

Comment: I was in the ISE when I tested, both; that's not actually supposed to matter however. As far as the type of `$test`, it seems to be an anonymous `PSObject` in PS2; in PS5, where it does actually assign the result of the command, it's a `DateTime`.

Comment: idk could be an ISE bug should be able to work without parentheses

Comment: I should note that the parens are _probably_ necessary when using a compound command and the pipeline, as in the querent's original posting. Without them, there can be some ambiguity about just what gets assigned to the variable.

Comment: yes that majkes sense, without them i believe it was just storing the get child item command without the where-object

Comment: No, there is no need for parentheses, even with multi-segment pipelines, because the assignment operator has the _lowest_ precedence. Try `$v = Get-Date | % { "[$_]" }; $v`, and you'll get the current date enclosed in `[...]` - see [`Get-Help about_Operator_Precedence`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847842.aspx)

Comment: I'm genuinely curious to learn what would make PSv2 behave the way you describe - I don't even see it in the PSv2 ISE.
I encourage both of you to come up with reproducible steps to produce the symptom - _that_ will be of interest to future readers.
As it stands, this answer is a distraction, because it doesn't explain goldenwest's symptoms (note that in a comment they state that they get _no_ output), advises something unnecessary (the use of `(…)`),
and contains slightly misleading information (that the output is an _array_, which is only true for _2 or more_ output objects).

Comment: the output of that specific command behaves sort of like an array tho and if you call directory it will give you write time so im not sure, hence the reason why i posted this question. I posted it for help and while this conversation has been informing it has strayed far away from initial question and into syntax